# Don't require password on wakeup while explorer.exe is killed

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, kiosk, auto-login, powercfg

I need to configure Windows 10 Kiosk Auto-login tablets that don't require a password when they go to sleep.

Right now, our tablets autologin on a local user, which kills explorer.exe at login and opens a fullscreen Kiosk app on Google Chrome. Killing explorer is a necessity in order to deactivate edge swipes because we use Chinese CHUWI tablets which are not from MS.

So, I did activate the "Don't require a password" in Power Options, using these commands:

```
powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX %GUID% SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 0
powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX %GUID% SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 0
```

The problem is that while explorer.exe is killed, the tablet still asks for my password, regardless of AC/DC Power Setting indices, but ends up working again after I launch explorer. Does anybody know a workaround? I appreciate for your help.

Comment: My bad. Edited.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm just not going to use sleep mode.